# Multiply column by another column in r

Tags: r

I need to calculate actual value at certain point instead of relative changes at that point. I have tipical time-series data (% to previous period) and need to get actual value of asset at some time. Something like:

> ```
> Day0 Day1  Day2  Day3
> 100  1.05  1.05  1.05
> 100  1.01  1.01  1.01
> 100  0.99  0.99  0.99
> ```

should looks like:

> ```
> Day0  Day1  Day2    Day3
> 100   105  110.25  115.76
> 100   101  102.01  103.03
> 100   99   98.01   97.02
> ```

I believe I must use `replace` and `apply` here, but I have difficulties with 1st column. I dont know how to avoid it using `function`, which multiply each column by the previous one.

Comment: Not on a pc right now, but it should be something like apply(df,1,cumprod).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF[] <- Reduce(`*`, DF, accumulate = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
  Day0 Day1   Day2     Day3
1  100  105 110.25 115.7625
2  100  101 102.01 103.0301
3  100   99  98.01  97.0299
```

This works because a data.frame is a list of columns.

---

Or, as @akrun suggested:

```
t(apply(DF, 1, cumprod))
```

Comment: Very nice one. Kudos.

Comment: @Frank It's okay.  You can include that in the mix.